# Understanding graph layering approximation algorithms

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, approximation

I've been trying to understand the Graph Layering Approximation Algorithms for both Set Cover and Feedback Vertex Set problems. I am using Vijay V. Vazirani's "Approximation Algorithms" book. So let me show you my train of thougts based on pages 17-18 from this book.

The weight function for nodes, based on their degrees is used: $w(v) = c * deg(v)$ where:

c - constant, such that c>0
v - vertex of a graph
deg(v) - degree of a vertex v

So now we take a graph, compute $c = min{(w(v) / deg(v))}$ for all vertices, then we compute $t(v) = c * deg(v)$, and for all vertices define $w'(v) = w(v) - t(v)$

We remove all vertices for which $w'(v) == 0$ and we repeat until all vertices have weight of 0.

**Now for my problem:**
If I assign $c = 1$, then function $w(v)$ for each vertex:

$w(v) = 1 * deg(v) = deg(v)$.
$min{(w(v) / deg(v))} = min{(deg(v)/deg(v))} = 1$.
   $t(v) = deg(v)$
   $w'(v) = deg(v) - deg(v) = 0$.

So for all vertices in step one I have weights 0 ALWAYS. Am I missing something? Should $c$ vary for each vertex? If so, how should I assign $c$ to vertices? Is there some range of integers? *Example of using this algorithm on a small graph would be nice*, because I am not very good at reading Math notation

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the value of $c$ is calculating in each iteration using this formula:
$$c=\min\left( \frac{w(v)}{\deg(v)} \right),$$
and there is no constant $c$ for assigning weight to all vertices.

Second, $c$ is a real parameter, not an integer.

Third, I think, in Vijay V. Vazirani's "Approximation Algorithms" book, page 19, first equation is wrong and had to define as follow:
$$
w(v)\le\sum_{i\le j}t_i(v)
$$
or

$$
w(v)=t_j(v).
$$

Because $v \in W_j$ and in $j^{th}$ iteration $w'_j(v)=w(v)-t_j(v)=0\Rightarrow w(v)=t_j(v)$.

Comment: I finally understand what $w'$ is. In each iteration $w$ replaced with calculated $w'$. With this method we can prove $w(v)=\sum_{i\le j}{} {t_i(v)}$.

Comment: It's been over 3 years, but thanks for answer anyway! If I remember correctly I came to a realization that this algorithm doesn't give an answer, but instead simplifies the graph, eliminating nodes that are not part of cycles, so that we can use brute-force algorithm on a smaller subset of graph and get result faster.

Comment: @Celebes The algorithm does give an answer. It is argued in the first part of the proof.

Answer (score 0):

You use the wrong definition for $t(v)$. Instead of $c*deg(v)$ it is defined as $c*\delta(v)$ the decrease in cyclomatic number after removing $v$.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I used layering algorithm for vertex cover algorithm by mistake, but problem stays the same, which is how to assign weights (c)

Answer (score 0):

You should search "local ratio for approximation algorithms". This is the popular name of the layering algorithm in Vazirani's book. Bar-Yehuda has many papers on it. Below is the link to one of them:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304020808731013

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).